# Is there any way in Flutter to let two users share one screen?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a game where two people can connect and share the same screen, like in a chess game. So each user can play on his screen and both parties see what is going on

Comment: Do you mean over the network? Using Bluetooth? Or simply rendering two `Chess` widgets and letting them take up half of the screen each?

Comment: You're new to this, but this question doesn't contain an actual programming problem. Show us what you have tried to make the game, and what the exact problem is. Please also read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Connecting over a network